# Error trying rename a file

Tags: vb.net, io, file-rename, file-copying

**Hi community!**

I have an application in VB.Net, in the user's computer is located in program files.
The users run always the program as an Administrators.

But in some cases; when the program try to rename a file in the program files the program throws the following exception:

The given path's format is not supported.
SOURCE = System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath

Also, happens when I try to copy a file.

The application does the rename or copy automatically and it's the same name for all the users

Example:

```
Rename(vOld, vNew)
FileCopy(vOld, vNew)
```

This exception only happen in Win7.

Somebody have an idea what is the reason to some users appear this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it's my fault!

-_-'

I'm trying to rename this path:

```
C:\_MyFile.xlsx
```

To:

```
C:\MyFile.xlsx
```

In my computer all works fine because I have the both files (The users only has the file with the underscore).
When the program try to validate it try to rename the file `"_C:\MyFile.xlsx"` to `"C:\MyFile.xlsx"`

The exception don't give much information about my error...

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when the user provides an invalid file name, for example one that includes colons.

You should validate that the user-entered file name does not contain any of the values in [System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx).

Comment: mmmm not it's the case. The application do it automatically and it's the same name for all the users.

Comment: take a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918375/c-sharp-file-copy-throws-exception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported

Comment: mmmm, not, the filename is very simple. This is not my case.